# Image source not shown

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hello I have created a xamarin cross platform app.

I have an Image which is set for each platform iOS and Android.
If I tap on this image it should be changed to another image from resource.

Project:

[image]

Mainpage.xaml

```
<Frame BorderColor="Teal" BackgroundColor="White">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition 
                Width="100"
            />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition 
                Height="100"
            />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            x:Name="imgEnglisch"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="White">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="IbtnEnglisch_Clicked" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <Image.Source>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
                        <OnPlatform.iOS>
                            <FileImageSource File="england_flag"/>
                        </OnPlatform.iOS>
                        <OnPlatform.Android>
                            <FileImageSource File="england_flag.png"/>
                        </OnPlatform.Android>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

EmbeddedImage.cs

```
namespace VoTa
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Source))]
    public class EmbeddedImage : IMarkupExtension
    {
       public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
                return null;

            return ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(EmbeddedImage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        }
    }
}
```

tapped event:

```
private void IbtnEnglisch_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    imgEnglisch.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Images.england_flag_mercury.jpg");

    //also tried
    imgEnglisch.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("VoTa.Images.england_flag_mercury.jpg", 
    typeof(EmbeddedImage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

}
```

If I tap on the image, nothing is shown. The image property ONBUILD is set to EMBADDED RESOURCE.

If I debug it with the following code, the file can be found correctly.

```
var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("found resource: " + res);
}
```

So can you please help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please add the image in the Android and iOS Resource folder
The name will be the same in both Resource folder
After that specify the only name in

> image.source("england_flag")

Comment: Thanks it works now. But one question: Why is it not possible to make one image folder in the project and use this?

Comment: It is possible but you have to do extra work for that. This is the best way because you will add images in different sizes like in Android drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi folder and in iOS add-in Assets-xcassets.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the image Images folder of Forms project like screenshot below with the `Embedded resource` Build Action, you could set load the resource with the code below.

Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
  imgEnglisch.Source= ImageSource.FromResource("XamarinDemo.Images.lighthouse.jpg");

XamarinDemo: Project Name
Images: Folder Name
lighthouse.jpg: Image File Name
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't work. If I tap on the image the initial picture is hide and no other picture is shown.

Comment: I have uploaded my screenshot. The code works well. Please check your image build action and the parameter(Project Name, Folder Name, Image File Name) of the image.

Comment: as you can see the screenshots in my question the image is set in the IMAGES folder and I have double check once again the paramters and they are correct. Is it maybe related to the XAML, where I set the IMAGE.SOURCE for each platform?

Comment: I used the same XAML with yours. Wait for a monent. I would upload the project.

Comment: You could check the source file on GitHub. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/ImageWithEmbeddedResource

Comment: Thank you, I have double check it once again. No difference between your test app and my app, but for some reason the image is not shon for me...I have no idea why this happen

Comment: I have debuged again and found the following error: ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource

Comment: I get this in the output window when I tap on the image